# How to delete the matrices which contain specific elements

Tags: filtering

I have a list which contains some matrices. Some of the matrices contain `Overflow[]` elements. I want to delete these matrices.

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {1, 2}},
 {{1, 2}, {Overflow[], Overflow[]}, {Overflow[], Overflow[]}}, 
 {{Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[]}, {Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[]}, 
  {Overflow[], Overflow[], Overflow[]}}}
```

The result should be only  `{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}`.

Comment: `Select[ list, Not[ MemberQ[ #, Overflow[], Infinity] ] & ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   DeleteCases[list, _?(MemberQ[Flatten[#], Overflow[]] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[_?(FreeQ[Overflow[]])] @ list
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}}

Also

```
DeleteCases[_?(Not @* FreeQ[Overflow[]])] @ list
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}}

```
DeleteCases[Except @ _?(FreeQ[Overflow[]])] @ list
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}}

Answer (score 0):

```
Pick[list, FreeQ[#, Overflow[]] & /@ list]
```

> [image]